# How to tell webpack to bundle using the ESM version of a dependency instead of the CJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, es6-modules, tree-shaking

We use `react-native-web-lottie` which is distributed in two versions:

- `dist`: format `CJS`
- `src`: format `ESM`

The beggining of their `package.json` looks like:

```
  "name": "react-native-web-lottie",
  "version": "1.4.4",
  "description": "React Native for Web implementation of Lottie",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "main-es": "src/index.js",
  "module": "src/index.js",
```

By default, our webpack configuration [here](https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/blob/master/web/config/webpack.config.js) will bundle the `CJS`.

We want to take benefits of tree shaking to optimize our bundle size, I believe this can be done only through ESM module.

How can I tell Webpack to bundle using the `ESM` module, do tree shaking, and distribute the final webapp bundle into CJS?